# Ground cherry problem

Tags: fruits

I'm having a weird problem with almost all of my ground cherry plants. The berry, while still on the plant, ends up poking through the paper. it's hard to describe but it's like the paper doesn't grow with the berry and the berry just pokes through the end. Has anybody else had this happen? Any suggestion?[image: weird ground cherry fruit]

Comment: Can you add a photo of the plants as well please